# Try to create BLOB from HttpServletRequest Body

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I try to create a BLOB from HttpServletRequest's Body in a Filter.
I did it like this:

```
Blob blob=Hibernate.createBlob(request.getInputStream());
```

but this method is deprecated.
what else can i do?

Comment: you may try this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/LobHelper.html#createBlob%28java.io.InputStream,%20long%29 - the problem is if you don't have the blob size (in this case, it seems some DBs work with size = -1)

Comment: @Leo DB is oracle and i try it by request.getContentLength() for second parameter.it's deprecated too.

Comment: When you serve some content with http, you can or you cannot declare the size of the content you're serving. Of course, it's always nice if you do, otherwise you'll get those downloading progress bars that never ends :-) and this is the case in many times, that's why I think this method was deprecated. The problem, obviously, is that you'll have to retrieve first, then check the size, then input it again locally :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this:

```
byte[] b=IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
blob=Hibernate.createBlob(b, LogDAO.getInstance().getSession());
```

and it works...